# Unable to open h2o in anaconda

Tags: anaconda, h2o

after following the instruction in http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#install-in-python, I was able to install h2o v 3.16.0.2. I was also able to use command line instructions mentioned in the above website and test that it is working.

```
python
import h2o
h2o.init()
h2o.demo("glm")
```

However, when I launch anaconda spyder, I am not able to import h2o. How do I link the h2o I have installed and bring it into Spyder python?

Update:
I have already tried {conda install -c anaconda h2o } which is mentioned on Anaconda.org, but that installs older ver 3.10 of h2o and that did not work either.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is due to your python environment. When you install Anaconda, you need to use anaconda pip, to ensure that the installed packages are available in conda.

The short answer is you can install the lastest stable version of H2O (3.16.0.2 as of today) using conda via `h2oai` channel instead of `anaconda` channel (h2o maintains it's own channel):

```
conda install -c h2oai h2o
```

this should solve your issue.

But more generally, the packages will appear in conda if you use anaconda pip. You can check which pip is being used by doing

`which pip`

and making sure that the path to the pip is within your anaconda distribution; something like `/home/<userdir>/anaconda/bin/pip` instead of `/usr/bin/pip`

Same is true also for Python. Try checking if starting Python in terminal points to anaconda Python by doing `which python`. If that's not the case, than you would need to add the conda installation of Python to your PATH variable. Please refer to conda docs for instructions https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html

It would have been helpful if you had included information regarding your operating system in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Window 7, I tried the command conda install -c h2oai h2o, and it still didn't fix it.

Comment: I also verified that both python.exe and pip.exe were in anaconda folder using 'where' command.

Comment: try checking the h2o installation `conda list h2o`. If the correct version is installed and spyder still can't see the library, you need to check that spyder's python interpreter is set to anaconda python (in preferences menu). You can also add the correct path to `PYTHONPATH` manager in spyder.

Comment: Thanks, last night, I uninstalled everything, Then I installed anaconda latest stable version. I tried conda install -c h2oai h2o, but that didn't work. then I tried pip install h2o and that seems to work now. My guess was same as yours that the path was not getting recognized. Thanks for all your help.